Understanding Why Families of Solutions with Scalar or Exponential Constants Don't Intersect
I am quite new to differential equations and I have a question of the intuition behind why some forms of general solutions do not intersect given an initial condition.
Some general solutions are a family of the same curve but shifted by a particular constant, $C$, with the example:

$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = f(x) \Longrightarrow y = F(x) + C$

With this example, any particular coordinate point is attached to a specific function within the family of curves given by $F(x) + C$. It makes intuitive sense why these functions will never intersect.
However, the arbitrary constant ($C$) of differential equation's general solution may not shift the function additively, with the example:

Ex: $\frac{dy}{dx} = x + y \Longrightarrow y = -x + 1 + Ce^{x}$

My specific question is how can it be explained intuitively why general solutions that contain the constant $C$ as a scalar or exponential term don't intersect. My immediate thought is that a general solution like $y = C \cdot g(x)$ will share some root with any constant $C$, I understand that this is incorrect but I want to know why.
Please correct me on any terminologies I used incorrectly, or if I am missing anything in my fundamental understanding. Thank you.

It's the Picard-Lindelöf Existence and Uniqueness Theorem: under suitable conditions, there is exactly one solution to the differential equation with a given initial value.  If two solutions intersected, they would both satisfy the same initial value condition at the point of intersection.
[EDIT] Here's my try at an intuitive explanation.
A good way to think of the first-order differential equation
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y) $$
is that it tells you that at every point $(x,y)$ on a solution curve, the slope must be $f(x,y)$.  Imagine that at every point of the $x-y$ plane there is a little "road sign" that says, "If you are here, go that way" (indicating the direction corresponding to slope $f(x,y)$). The solution curve wanders over the $x$, $y$ plane, following the road signs at each point it goes through. So if $f(2,3)$ happens to be $4$, and a solution curve passes through the point $(2,3)$, it must have slope $4$ at that point.
The Existence and Uniqueness Theorem says, basically, that if $f(x,y)$ is sufficiently well-behaved, you can always follow the road signs and, moreover, since at every point you are told in what direction to go, there is no free choice involved: the initial condition uniquely determines the solution.
The surprising thing, to my mind, is that this might not true if $f(x,y)$ is not sufficiently well-behaved.  For example, the differential equation $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = y^{1/3} $$ with initial condition $y(0) = 0$ is satisfied by both $y(x) = 0$ and $$ y(x) = \cases{ (2x/3)^{3/2} & if $x \ge 0$\cr 0 & otherwise} $$

Thank you that clears a lot up! I suppose now I would love to find any sort of intuitive explanation for this theorem given visually or through a sort of analogy.

Edit: Thank you so much for the intuitive explanation!
